# How to add a column with progressive number based on condition

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to add a column to my existing data set. 
The data set has three columns:

- `Student` (which is the column with the participant ID),
- `Week` (the number of the week of the year during which the data were collected),
  and
- `Day` (the number of the weekday during which the data were
  collected).

Now, a new column `Obs` that I am trying to create would contain a progressive number (from 1 to n) referring to the week during which every student was tested.

I have tried to use `group_by` in combination with `rep` but it does not seem to produce the result I want:

```
Week <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4)
Day <- c(1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 5, 1, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5)
Student <- c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C")
fake.db <- data.frame(Student, Week, Day)

library(dplyr)
fake.db %>%
  group_by(Student) %>% 
  mutate(Obs = rep(1:length(Student), each = Week))
#   Student  Week   Day   Obs
#   <fct>   <dbl> <dbl> <int>
# 1 A           1     1     1
# 2 A           1     2     2
# 3 A           1     3     3
# 4 B           2     2     1
# 5 B           2     3     2
# 6 B           2     5     3
# 7 B           3     1     4
# 8 B           3     3     5
# 9 C           4     2     1
#10 C           4     3     2
#11 C           4     4     3
#12 C           4     5     4
```

What I would like to obtain is different. For the first week of data collection, `1` should be reported, and for the students for whom data were collected during a second week, `2` should be reported, etc.:

```
#   Student Week Day Obs
#1        A    1   1   1
#2        A    1   2   1
#3        A    1   3   1
#4        B    2   2   1
#5        B    2   3   1
#6        B    2   5   1
#7        B    3   1   2
#8        B    3   3   2
#9        C    4   2   1
#10       C    4   3   1
#11       C    4   4   1
#12       C    4   5   1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One `dplyr` possibility could be:

```
fake.db %>%
 group_by(Student) %>%
 mutate(Obs = cumsum(!duplicated(Week)))

  Student  Week   Day   Obs
   <fct>   <dbl> <dbl> <int>
 1 A           1     1     1
 2 A           1     2     1
 3 A           1     3     1
 4 B           2     2     1
 5 B           2     3     1
 6 B           2     5     1
 7 B           3     1     2
 8 B           3     3     2
 9 C           4     2     1
10 C           4     3     1
11 C           4     4     1
12 C           4     5     1
```

It groups by "Student" column and calculates the cumulative sum of non-duplicate "Week" values.

Or:

```
fake.db %>%
 group_by(Student) %>%
 mutate(Obs = with(rle(Week), rep(seq_along(lengths), lengths)))
```

It groups by "Student" column and creates a run-length type group ID around "Week" column".

Or:

```
fake.db %>%
 group_by(Student) %>%
 mutate(Obs = dense_rank(Week))
```

It groups by "Student" column and ranks the values in "Week" column.

Answer (score 2):

What I understand the issue to be is that you want to count the weeks since the first test week for each student. I.e. Week 2 is student B's first week of testing, so it gets `Obs = 1`. That means you can do a grouped mutate:

```r
library(dplyr)
fake.db <- structure(list(Student = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), Week = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4), Day = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 5, 1, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
fake.db %>%
  group_by(Student) %>%
  mutate(Obs = Week - min(Week) + 1)
#> # A tibble: 12 x 4
#> # Groups:   Student [3]
#>    Student  Week   Day   Obs
#>    <fct>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 A           1     1     1
#>  2 A           1     2     1
#>  3 A           1     3     1
#>  4 B           2     2     1
#>  5 B           2     3     1
#>  6 B           2     5     1
#>  7 B           3     1     2
#>  8 B           3     3     2
#>  9 C           4     2     1
#> 10 C           4     3     1
#> 11 C           4     4     1
#> 12 C           4     5     1
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

A brief method with `by`

```
unlist(by(fake.db, fake.db[, 1], function(x) as.numeric(factor(x[, 2]))))
# A1 A2 A3 B1 B2 B3 B4 B5 C1 C2 C3 C4 
#  1  1  1  1  1  1  2  2  1  1  1  1
```

***Data***

```
fake.db <- structure(list(Student = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), 
    Week = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4), Day = c(1, 
    2, 3, 2, 3, 5, 1, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see if there is a non-zero difference

```
fake.db %>%
  group_by(Student) %>% 
  arrange(Week) %>%
  mutate(Obs = cumsum(c(1, diff(Week)!=0)))
```

or if they values arne't numeric, you can compare to the lag value

```
fake.db %>%
  group_by(Student) %>% 
  arrange(Week) %>%
  mutate(Obs = cumsum(Week != lag(Week, default=first(Week))) + 1)
```